# Android Battery Historian - docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for gcr.io/android-battery-historian

Tags: android, docker, battery

I really need to see the battery stats of one of the app I am working on. I have been following below steps from the official Android documentation.

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/battery-historian.html#gather-data

I have achieved steps 1 to 10 & also managed to get the batterystats.txt & bugreport.zip out the Android Device.

I have installed docker & was trying to execute Step 11 but it throws the following error.

[image]

I tried removing the '--' ahead of run and managed to get rid of the error. Now I am executing the below command and seeing the another error as screenshot below.

[image]

I have seen for other people that it downloads the battery historian image to the local machine in case if it isn't found locally. The same case is not with me. I have tried logging in to the docker as well but no lock.

Is there any way I can download the battery historian image to the local machine & execute the command that belongs to step 11? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I managed to see the battery stats of an app. I would like to write down here hoping that it would be helpful to someone doing the same.

I would like to say thanks to this guy over the Github who has gone extra mile working on this - https://github.com/google/battery-historian/issues/125#issuecomment-361369864

Below are the steps.

**(1) Download the battery historian image first -**
Use the command `docker pull kenyee/battery_historian` to download the image to your local machine as the screenshot below.

[image]

**(2) Run the battery historian image -**
Run the command `docker run -d -p 1234:9999 kenyee/battery_historian` as the screenshot below.

[image]

**(3) Open battery historian using browser**
Open the http://localhost:1234/ to your browser. 1234 stands for the port number we have defined with the command above. If you decide to use the port number other than 1234 in the command above, the URL will also be changed accordingly. As soon as we hit the enter, browser will show up the battery historian as the screenshot below.

[image]

**(4) View battery stats** 
Upload your bugreport file, hit submit & you will see the battery stats of an app as the screenshot below.

[image]

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it saves my time.

Comment: Previously, it had shown the device estimated power use per process. Now it didn't show that information. Can anyone suggest me how would I get that information?